# Can you help us read this handwriting from a leather wallet?

Tags: handwriting

It is very old and we are trying to understand what it says. 
[image]

Here is a [link to a big version on wikicommons](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/What-does-it-say.png).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm thinking it is a phone number and name like "Johnson - Harry pooler - 13 aven - Jirus city  th 2 -1821   (with the last part being a phone extension..  see the format of names here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange_names - Jones John 123 Anystreet BUtterfield 5-1212

Comment: Thank you for looking. Sorry it is off topic but this page came up when googling handwriting help. We did considder the last part a date, but interesting idea it may be a street.

Comment: @ndasusers that's a tricky one! The first name looks like Johan or Johann to me. The next word could be Hatiz or Hafiz. If it's Hafiz, that is a Muslim honorific title for anyone who learns to recite the Koran from memory. It could be Jinn City which is a place in Pakistan and Jinn are spirits in Islam mythology. Baphomet was a jinn worshipped by The Knights of the Templar and that could say Baph - a short form maybe? The date looks like 1827 to me. But this is all complete conjecture. I'm not sure you'll ever be able to decipher it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Writing, ndasusers. We are unlike other Q&A sites, in that we focus only on questions which can help other people. As no one else is going to have this question, your question is off topic for us.

That being said, I see no harm in giving you my best attempt. Realize that I am by no means an expert. Just a guy with Photoshop running it through contrast filters.

The first word is very clearly `John`. It looks like there's a `:` after that. Following that we have `Hat`, and what could be `tf` or `lf`. So `hattf` or `hatlf`. Neither makes much sense. Next word clearly begins with `p`, followed by `s` or possibly a vowel. Then we have what I believe is a vowel, though it could be `i` or `e`. I would hazard a guess that the word ends with `ded`, but the last two letters are impossible to make out. They are followed by `—`.

Next line. Either a `13` or a super sloppy `B`. Then you have `a`. I'd like to say it's followed by `v`, but there's a wierd tail on the end, so I'm not sure about that. It looks like the word finishes with `h`. Another dash. I would hazard a guess at the word `five`, but it looks like there's one letter too many at the end. Next word appears to start with `c`, but it could just be a fancy beginning of a `t` or `l` - whichever the next letter is. I feel certain the final letter is `t`.

Final line looks to start with `the`. Then a clear `2`. Dash. `182/-`. That last bit is underlined.

Based on the three line structure and the appearance of numbers, I would guess this is an address. However, I have absolutely no context.

Comment: Could you know if anyone ever wrote a date like this in the 1800's June the 2 . 1827 A/D ?

Comment: @ndasusers - I don't think that's a "June".  Pretty sure Thomas Myron's right that the first two letters are "Th". "18.2/-" would I believe have been a common way of writing 18 pounds, 2 shillings and no pence in the UK pre-decimalisation, so could be the price of something.

Answer (score 0):

John Hall's Pocket-book.

Jim's (something)

other 2 1802/-

Comment: Thank you for helping - we guessed the same name too and we are reasonbly sure there is a date at the end.

Comment: @ndasusers I wonder if the second line ends in At/10 ... as a unit of cost/price. Wikipedia seems to think saying something 'at number' is a means of listing cost/price.

Comment: Thanks. After the suggestion and a close look at the large image, there could look like a very faded 't' near the A on the end of the second line. 1802 would mean a really small 0 after the 8. We guessed it was just a thick 8 tail.

Comment: @ndasusers I like to think that it was a note on the history of the wallet. I like to think it was a pocketbook from John hall and then Jim someone, and one of them was 10 (At/10) when he got it. That the birth date of one was 1802 and he was not deceased when the note was written.